# Solve $3+e^{2t}=7e^{2t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to solve $3+e^{2t}=7e^{2t}$. My textbook solution says it's $t=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ whereas I got $t=\frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{1}{2})$

My working:

$$3+e^{2t}=7e^{2t}$$
$$3=6e^{2t}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}=e^{2t}$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2t$$
$$t=\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $t=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$

Comment: You did nothing wrong. $\frac12 \ln \frac12 = \ln \sqrt{\frac12}$, and $ \ln \frac12 =\ln(2^{-1})= -\ln2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that
$$t_{\text{yours}}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\ln(2^{-1}) = \frac{1}{2}(-1)\ln(2)} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2) = t_{\text{book's}}$$

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to follow this. Is it possible to add some more granular steps in between?

Comment: i.e. how does `$\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2}ln(2)$`?

Comment: @DougFir Is it clear with the edit?

Comment: Yes! It's clicked now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong. Use the fact that$$\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)=\log\left(\left(\frac12\right)^{1/2}\right)=\frac12\log\left(2^{-1}\right)=-\frac12\log(2).$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the logarithm power rule:

The logarithm of $x$ raised to the power of $y$ is $y$ times the logarithm of $x$.

$$\log(x^ y) = y \cdot \log(x)$$

In your case is:
$$y=-0.5,
x=2$$